# Page is not getting refreshed which was implemented using C# and angularjs for html5Mode(true)

Tags: c#, angularjs

**This is the routing page:**

```
var testModule= angular.module('latModule', ['ngRoute', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ngResource']);

testModule.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",
    function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when("/test", {
            templateUrl: "/App/Test/test.html",
            controller: "testController"
        })
        .when("/test1", {
            templateUrl: "/App/Test1/test1.html",
            controller: null
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

**C# code (in C# home controller):**

```
var templatePage = Convert.ToString(RouteData.Values["url"]);
```

using this C# code snippet the url gets retrieved and redirects to client side homeCtroller. Through the above $routeProvider the application reloads the respective page. But for the first time only page is getting refreshed. When I try to refresh again the page is not getting reloaded. What may be the issue in this case ?

Comment: so could you please tell me clearly explain which page are u wanna refresh for which request like `\test` or `\test1`

Comment: For every page I am facing the same issue.

Comment: On click of F5 it hits the server side home controller and redirects to client side router .e.g; when I am refreshing test.html the flow gets complete from server side and It residrects to index.cshtml -> homeCtrl(client side).

Comment: Here in homeCtrl I am trying to load the test controller .But the flow breaks  here only.It doesn't reload the test.html & testController.

Comment: can you tell me do you have separate app.js file.? It contains the angular application name and other module dependency ..do you have it?

Comment: No.In my implementation 1.index.cshtml + homeCtrl 2.route.js. These three files are   there.

Comment: In angular side I am asking frnd please check your client side code

Comment: Or please check in your index.html file has your `testController.js`  path `<script></scrpt>`

Comment: s please post the route.js file may I asked that one ,.Lets see our luck!!

Comment: The first section of my code I have posted is only the route.js

Comment: ok do you post the homeController where your trying to redirect to The new page ?